# SQL sum quantity depending on field name

Tags: sql, database, sum

How would I go about adding the quantity of a column to each other depending on another columns name?

For example I have 3 columns:

```
NAME:      StockCode:    Qty:
Blackbirds TO12          2
Blackbirds TO14          4
Lions      TO55          54
Tigers     TO41          2
Lions      TO41          4
```

How would I add the qty together for both the blackbirds and lions, so that there is only one row, so the result would be as follows:

```
NAME:      StockCode:     Qty:
Blackbirds TO12           6
Lions      TO41           58
Tigers     TO32           2
```

Comment: You could use GROUP BY but the stockcodes differ e.g. for Lions you have T055 and T041. How do you determine which one to use?

Comment: the stockcode is only used to get all products with the that stockcode, all stockcodes refer to one product, just different colourways.

Comment: Ah ok, so in this case, you are not interested in that column? As you are only interested in getting the sum of each product?

Comment: Yes, the stockcode is to filter from other products, I want to add the quantity up for each name, so any name that is blackbirds add the quantities together and display in one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(QTY) as qty FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY NAME
```

PS: Since the `StockCode` are different for same `NAME`, They cannot be included in the `GROUP BY`.
Incase, `StockCode` doesn't matter and you need just the `SUM` based on `NAME`, then you could use the below solution.

```
SELECT NAME,StockCode, SUM(QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME) as qty FROM [YourTable]
```

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like the rule for "stock code" is to find the smallest value.

```
SELECT NAME, min(stockCode), SUM(QTY) as qty 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY NAME
```